# how to adjust the width of all the right or left elements at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs(sibblings) and on drag and resize of one of them, according to wether its being resized to west or east i would like to either increase or decrease all the other sibblings widths accordingly.
[image]

```
$(function () {
    var west;
    var east;
    var clientX;

    $("#resizable1").resizable({
        start: function (event, ui) {
             west = $(event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-resizable-w');
             east = $(event.srcElement).hasClass('ui-resizable-e');
             clientX = event.clientX;
        },
        resize: function (event, ui) {

            if (east) {
                //decrease one by one --?
                $(this).nextAll().css('width', --? );
            }
        }
    });


});
```

Comment: What's your HTML mark-up? How do you define a row? Is there a class-name to distinguish the left from the centre, or right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set width to:

```
if (east) {
     //decrease one by one
     var newWidth = ($('#resizable1').width() - $(this).outerWidth(true)) / $(this).nextAll().length
     ...
}
```

EDIT:
How do the 3rd and 4rd sibling react when you resize the second one? 
When calculating the remaining space, I only took the first one into account... if they fill the remaining space, yout must add up all outerWidths from the previous sibling instead of just taking $(this).outerWidth(true).

btw, the above code is not tested, just a suggestion to get remaining space to fill.

Answer (score 0):

Make them all share the same width variable, decrease or increase the variable to affect all the div's at the same time.

Either by manually setting every divs size by calling a function and using the same variable as parameter for all of the calls.

Or make the divs share a css class and call the resize function on all the html elements sharing that css class.

**EDIT:**

Ah i completely miss understood you...
Make all the divs sizes relative and floating, then they should fill their parent.

Comment: if he resizes the second resizable, this wont work ... third and fourth must fill out te remaining space I think ... Question is noot very clear ...